# Cytoscape.js partial layouter

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js

Is there a "real" partial layouting option in Cytoscape.js?

I've tried the following suggested options :

1. Using the Arbor layouter and locking the nodes I don't want to re-layout
2. Execute the layouter only on some elements in the graph using the makeLayout function and setting the avoidOverlap option to true on layouter that supply this option.

In both cases the layouter didn't take into account existing nodes that were locked or not part of the layouter nodes list which led to overlapping nodes in the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:

(1) A layout is aware only of the elements in it.

(2) Locked nodes can not be moved at all as long as they're locked.

You can run a layout on a subset of the graph, but that will not take into account other elements because of (1).  You can run a layout on the graph including locked nodes, but they will not be moved because of (2).

It sounds like you don't like the result of Arbor, so you should try a better force layout, like CoSE or Cola.  Locking elements and running a layout should work for simple usecases.  This approach and others are working fine in several of our projects with Cytoscape.js.